# How does keep Thread reliable to running

Tags: java, multithreading

I have create the program that technically running on 24*7.

By the way when the program does have invoke the new `Thread` sometimes the unexpected situation occurs like the thread doesn't run even though instruction was processed.

I tried to start my thread in different manner:

1. instantiate and start thread as local variable

   ```
   void method()
   {
       new Thread(new Runnable(){...}).start();
   }
   ```
2. same as 1) but assign its to object that allocate on main process

   ```
   Thread t;   //member of class own by main process
   void method()
   {
       t = new Thread(new Runnable(){...});
       t.start();
   }
   ```
3. use executorservice as delegator

   ```
   ExecutorserviceObject.execute(new Runnable(){...});
   ```

I rather got trouble at 1) when have a longtime running than 2) and 3).

I think the problem might be connected with garbage collector and/or thread scheduler.

How can this happen? Can anyone elaborate what's going on under the cover?

Comment: Please punctuate this unintelligible mess.

Answer (score 0):

The first case and the second case are pretty similar. Even if you don't assign the `Thread` object to the field/variable, it remains strongly reachable at least until the thread is finished (normally or exceptionally). Having it stored into field makes the further control of the thread easier (e.g. joining it or sending an interrupt), but it's not necessary.

Thus from the code posted in the question there should be no real difference between the first and second case. It's likely that your problem is in another piece of code.